# Sort array of objects by booleans, then by numbers (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have an array of objects, and I would like to sort them following these two rules (in order of priority):

The objets whose "departeYet" property is true must be at the beginning
The objects must then be sorted in numerical order (the "number" property)

This would be ok:

- true : 005
- true : 007
- true : 027
- false: 009
- false: 020

This is the structure of the part of the objects that interests us:

```
var notSortedData = {
                        number: number, // it's a string
                        departedYet: scheduled_date, // true or false
                    }

                    sortedTrains.push(notSortedData);
```

So, notSortedData is pushed in sortedTrains via a for loop.

Then, I need to sort it:

```
sortedTrains.sort(function(a, b) {
        // sorting algorithm here
    });
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe you understand how `sort` function works and what it's parameter function should return. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Short answer: you do not need to implement a *sorting algorithm*, all you need is a *compare* function.

Comment: just sort twice, first by numbers, then by booleans.

Comment: @ PM 77-1, Jonathan Gray found a way to sort it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this original answer (which I purposely made more verbose):

```
sortedTrains.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.departedYet === b.departedYet)
        return a.number-b.number;
    else if(a.departedYet)
        return -1;
    else return 1;
});
```

... or this even shorter equivalent:

```
sortedTrains.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.departedYet === b.departedYet)
        return a.number-b.number;
    return a.departedYet ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: this version of sort is more general 


    sortedTrains.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a.departedYet === b.departedYet)
            return 0;
        else if(a.departedYet)
            return -1;
        else return 1;
    });

Comment: @DamirBeylkhanov Your method will only sort by the departedYet value, it ignores the number value entirely.